# How to implement :parent selector in css

Tags: css

As shown in below code snippet I have got span elements within td. Also as mentioned in CSS section I have applied hover property for the DOM with class="open".
The problem is I want to get whole td element to get highlighted upon hover, and not just the span element. I thought if some kind parent selector would be there in css, but unfortunately it doesn't.
Is there any way out to get the desired result.

Thanx a lot in advance!!!!

```
<tr>                
    <td><span class="open">07</span></td>
    <td><span class="open">08</span></td>
    <td><span class="open">09</span></td>
    <td><span class="close">10</span></td>
    <td><span class="close">11</span></td>
</tr>
```

CSS:

```
.open:hover {
background-color: #42C0FB;
color: white;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: are you looking forward to make the corresponding <td> tag highlighted ?

Comment: this might help https://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/

Comment: why can't you place `class='open'` on td itself? you can always do anything with the span specifically i.e. `.open span`

Comment: @riyasharma you can do it by jquery only as i know

Comment: yes i m @NeophytePolyhistor

Comment: @srjt that was a proposal by some random person on the internet. First line "Let's be clear here, just in case someone is finding this from a search engine: **there are no parent selectors in CSS, not even in CSS3.**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1, set the span to be 100% of the `td` width or if that's not desirable then option 2 is to target the `td` element instead.

**Option 1**
CSS:

```
.open:hover {
background-color: #42C0FB;
color: white;
cursor: pointer;
width: 100%;
}
```

**Option 2**
HTML:

```
<tr>                
    <td class="open"><span>07</span></td>
    <td class="open"><span>08</span></td>
    <td class="open"><span>09</span></td>
    <td class="close"><span>10</span></td>
    <td class="close"><span>11</span></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: HI, is there any way I can target td elements like "highlight td elements which contain span with class = 'open' ". Is that feasible???

Comment: Give the class to the table data elements instead and only give the class to the elements with span's inside?

Comment: I cant give corresponding td elements class = 'open' as I change the position of span elements with animation. So It wont work after span elements have changed their position after animation.

Answer (score 0):

short answer: there is no parent selector and you cannot create any.

Solutions in your case:

1) declare the span as inline-block and set the size to the size of the td-element

2) adress the td instead of the span element in your css rules

Answer (score 0):

```
.open {
display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to highlight a container when hovering an element in it (in the OP's example, highlight the td when hovering on the span inside), you can do this by using labels and inputs.

Put a bunch of hidden inputs before the table and put the labels in the table cells. You can then target the entire cell because the input comes before, even if the label is inside.

```css
table {border:1px outset;}
td {border:1px inset; padding:1em;}
label {cursor:pointer; border:1px solid #ddd;}
input {display:none;}
#input07:hover ~ table td:first-child, 
#input08:hover ~ table td:nth-child(2), 
#input09:hover ~ table td:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #42C0FB;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input id="input07"><input id="input08"><input id="input09"><input id="input10"><input id="input11">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="input07" class="open">07</label></td>
    <td><label for="input08" class="open">08</label></td>
    <td><label for="input09" class="open">09</label></td>
    <td><label for="input10" class="close">10</label></td>
    <td><label for="input11" class="close">11</label></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```